# Exercise problem in group order & homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I came across this problem in class note but I am stuck:

Let *G* be a group of order 21, let *G'* be a group of order 35, and let φ
be a homomorphism from *G* to *G'*. Assume that *G* does not have a normal subgroup of
order 3. Show that φ(*g*) = 1 for each element *g* in *G*.

Any help or hints would be very much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You mean subgroup of order 7?

Comment: @Test123: I will email my professor if there is any typo. Order of 7 does make more sense. Thanks.

Comment: @A.Mangus It would have been easier but still as you can see below it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of $\varphi$ is a subgroup of $G'$ and so its order divides $35$. Moreover, this order is the index of the kernel of $\varphi$ in $G$, and so its order divides $21$. Hence, the order of the image of $\varphi$ is a common divisor of $35$ and $21$ and so divides $7$. But the order of the image cannot be $7$ because otherwise the order of the kernel would be $3$, and $G$ has no normal subgroup of order $3$. Thus, the order of the image of $\varphi$ is $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.

Comment: @A.Magnus, the image $\varphi(G)$ is isomorphic to the quotient $G/\ker\varphi$.

Comment: Could you explain " ... this order is the index of the kernel of phi of G, so its order devides 21." I think I understand the rest. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If $\varphi\colon G\to G'$ is a homomorphism, then $\ker\varphi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so its order is $1$, $3$, $7$ or $21$. It can't be $3$ by assumption. The homomorphism theorem says $\varphi$ induces an injective homomorphism
$$
\tilde\varphi\colon G/\ker\varphi\to G'
$$
such that $\operatorname{im}\tilde\varphi=\operatorname{im}\varphi$.

Call $H$ the image of $\varphi$; what order can $H$ have? Can $\ker\phi$ have order $1$ or $7$?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @A.Magnus I avoided giving the full answer, as I believe that hints are better when homework is involved.